# crown contacts relay

Tags: relay

I read in the datasheet of [this](http://www.dold.com/datenblaetter/Leiterplattenrelais/OA5601_en.pdf) PCB relay, that the relay has high switching reliability due to crown contacts.
What mean crown contacts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a characteristic of the forcibly guided relay, see [Relay terminology](http://www.altechcorp.com/PDFS/RelayTerminology.pdf)

Crown Contacts: Improved contact form to enforce
high contact stress on at least two spots on the
contact to penetrate any built-up contamination;
to maintain low contact resistance throughout the
life of a relay; and to increase the value of switchable
output voltage. Supports low current to high power
applications.